# The Mitchell order

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, model-theory, filters, large-cardinals

[Here](http://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~hart/onderwijs/set_theory/Jech/19-iterated_ultrapowers_and_LU.pdf), on page 358, I would like to know
if the $M$-ultrafilter $U_i$ on $κ$ is iterable for all $i$'s? 
How do we use and prove this fact?

And how can I see that $P^M(κ)=P(κ)$ and $M^κ⊂M$?

And finally how can I see that $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is in $M$?

Comment: Iterability is irrelevant to your question about the Mitchell order. If you are still interested in iterability, I'd suggest you post that as a separate question.

Comment: I've also noticed that you didn't mention the, in my opinion, key point of the proof - namely that $f$ represents $U_{n+1}$ in $\mathrm{Ult}_{U_n}(M)$. You may want to think about that for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's show that $M$ is closed under sequences of length $<\kappa$ - this will address your last question. Let's begin by remembering how sequences transform under $j$ in general:

> Suppose $f$ is a function with domain $\alpha$. Then for $\beta<\alpha$ we have $j(f)(j(\beta))=j(f(\beta))$.

This leaves room for several changes in moving from $f$ to $j(f)$. Obviously we can have $j(f(\beta))\not=f(\beta)$, but more importantly here the **domain** may change: we could have $j(\alpha)>\alpha$, in which case we will have inputs to $j(f)$ not corresponding to any inputs to $f$, and moreover the bits of $j(f)$ corresponding to bits of $f$ will move (if $j(\beta)>\beta$, then $j(f(\beta))$ is the $j(\beta)$th term of $j(f)$, not the $\beta$th term). The point here is that *if $\alpha$ is "small," then $f$ can't change too much when we hit it with $j$*.

---

First, let's show that $M$ is closed under $(<\kappa)$-sequences. (This will show why $\langle U_i\rangle_{i<\omega}$ is in $M$, since each $U_i$ is in $M$ and $\omega<\kappa$.) Suppose $a_\eta\in M$ with $a_\eta=j(b_\eta)$, for $\eta<\theta$ for some fixed $\theta<\kappa$. Then we have $j(\langle b_\eta\rangle_{\eta<\theta})=\langle a_\eta\rangle_{\eta<\theta}$: this is because $\theta<crit(j)$, so doesn't get "stretched." Phrased another way, any function $f$ with domain $\theta$ satisfies $$j(f)=\{(a, b): a\in\theta, b=j(f(a))\}.$$

Now what about sequences of length $\kappa$? Here we have a problem, since the sequence will "stretch" - e.g. $j(\langle \eta\rangle_{\eta<\kappa})=\langle\eta\rangle_{\eta<j(\kappa)}$. However, this is still fixable: all the "nonstandard" terms of the sequence that $j$ adds come **after** all the "standard" terms. If $f$ is a function with domain $\kappa$, we have $$j(f)\upharpoonright\kappa=\{(a,b): a\in\kappa, b=j(f(a))\}.$$

Now elements of $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ are (basically equivalent to) $\kappa$-sequences of ordinals, and every ordinal is in $M$ - so $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)\subseteq M$, hence $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)=\mathcal{P}(\kappa)^M$.

---

As to iterability, I don't see that it plays any role here, but I could be reading too quickly.

Comment: Iterability is not needed to show that the Mitchell order is well-founded.

Comment: @StefanMesken I did not think so, but since this is not my area I wanted to be cautious.

Comment: Why do we know, for $\theta<\kappa$, that $\langle a_\eta\rangle_{\eta <\theta}\in M$ but
$\langle\eta\rangle_{\eta <j(\kappa)}\notin M$?Where/how did we use the "largeness" of $j(\kappa)$i.e. $\kappa<j(\kappa)$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Please see my comment above. Thank you.

Comment: @NoahSchweber OP just made me aware that your answer doesn't actually show that $M$ is closed under $\kappa$-sequences. You show the weaker fact that $M$ is closed under $\kappa$-sequences whose elements are in $\mathrm{ran}(j)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative proof of the fact that $\mathcal{P}^M(\kappa) = \mathcal{P}(\kappa)$:

Since $M \subseteq V$ is transitive, we have $\mathcal{P}^M(\kappa) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\kappa)$. (Note that "$x \subseteq \kappa$" is expressible via a $\Sigma_0$-formula and hence absolute between transitive structures. Hence $M$ correctly identifies whether a given element $x \in M$ is a subset of $\kappa$ or not - but it could miss subsets of $\kappa$.)

Let $x \subseteq \kappa$. Let $\pi \colon V \to M$ be the canonical elementary embedding. Then 
$$M \models \pi(x) \subseteq \pi(\kappa)$$
and since this is absolute (see above), we have $\pi(x) \subseteq \pi(\kappa)$. Now, for any $\xi < \kappa$
$$
\begin{align*}
\xi \in x & \iff V \models \xi \in x \\
& \iff M \models \underbrace{\pi(\xi)}_{= \xi} \in \pi(x) \\
& \iff \xi \in \pi(x)
\end{align*}
$$
and thus $x = \pi(x) \cap \kappa \in M$. (Here we use that $M$ computes $a \cap b$ correctly for any $a,b \in M$.)

Essentially the same argument actually shows

*Claim.* $V_{\kappa +1}^M = V_{\kappa +1}$.

*Proof.* By the same argument as above (and absoluteness of the rank function) we have $V_{\kappa +1}^M \subseteq V_{\kappa +1}$. Conversely let $x \in V_{\kappa +1} = \mathcal P(V_{\kappa})$. It suffices to show that
$$
x = \{ y \in \pi(x) \mid \mathrm{rank}_{\in}(y) < \kappa \} = \{ y \in \pi(x) \mid M \models \mathrm{rank}_{\in}(y) < \kappa \}.
$$
Since "$\mathrm{rank}_{\in}(y) = \alpha$" is absolute between transitive models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$, we get the equality of the sets on the right hand side. Furthermore for any $y \in x$ we have $\mathrm{rank}_{\in}(y) < \kappa$ and thus $y = \pi(y) \in \mathrm{RHS}$. (Recall that $\mathrm{crit}(\pi)$ is the minimal rank of an element $z$ such that $\pi(z) \neq z$.) Conversely, if $y \in \mathrm{RHS}$, then $y = \pi(y) \in \pi(x)$ and thus - by elementarity - $y \in x$. Q.E.D.

---

As promised [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514937/the-mitchell-order-unclear-step-in-the-proof-of-well-foundedness/2514944?noredirect=1#comment5193815_2514944), I'll add a proof that $M$ is in fact closed under $\kappa$-sequences. Let $(x_i \mid i < \kappa)$ be a sequence such that $x_i \in M$ for all $i < \kappa$. Fix, for each $i < \kappa$, a function
$$
f_i \colon \kappa \to V
$$
such that $x_i = [f_i]$. (This is possible because $M= \mathrm{Ult}_{U_0}(V)$.) Define a function
$$
g \colon \kappa \to V
$$
as follows: For each $\xi < \kappa$
$$
g(\xi) \colon \xi \to V
$$
is such that for all $i < \xi$
$$
g(\xi)(i) = f_{i}(\xi).
$$
Using that $\kappa = [\mathrm{id}]$ (which is equivalent to $U_0$ being normal) and Łoś's Theorem, you can verify that
$$
[g] \colon \kappa \to M
$$
(in $M$) and that for all $i < \kappa$
$$
\{ \xi < \kappa \mid g(\xi)(i) = f_{i}(\xi) \} = \kappa \setminus (i+1) \in U_0,
$$
so that by Łoś's Theorem, for all $i < \kappa$,
$$
[g](i) = [f_i]
$$
and thus
$$
(x_i \mid i < \kappa) = ([f_i] \mid i < \kappa) = [g] \in M.
$$

Comment: Let $M = \mathrm{Ult}_U(M)$ for a normal ultrafilter $U$ on $\kappa$. Then, since the Mitchell order is anti-reflexive, $U \not \in \mathrm{Ult}_U(V)=M$ but $U \in V_{\kappa +2}$. This shows that $V_{\kappa+2}^M \subsetneq V_{\kappa+2}$, i.e. the result above is in fact optimal.

Comment: Do you mean "Let $M=\mathbb{Ult}_U(V)$" rather then "Let $M=\mathbb{Ult}_U(M)$"?

Comment: @user122424 Yes, I've actually made that mistake twice in my comment but apparently only spotted it once.

Comment: I do not understand your English.I'm a non-English speaker. Where have you made it twice?I can see it only once. And what is "sppoted"? Thank you for your comment and answer to my question.

Comment: @user122424 In an earlier version of my comment I also wrote - incorrectly - $U \not \in \mathrm{Ult}_{U}(M)$. I caught that error within the time limit to edit my comment and hence was able to correct that. However, I missed the second typo that you've discovered and am no longer able to edit my comment.

Comment: Also, is there a typo in the last line of the lemma 19.32, where is written $\mathbb{Ult}_{U_n}^M(M)$ instead of $\mathbb{Ult}_{U_n}^M(V)$?

Comment: @user122424 I don't even know what $\mathrm{Ult}^M_{U_n}(V)$ would mean... $\mathrm{Ult}^M_{U_n}(M)$ is the $M$-ultrapower by $U_n$ built inside of $M$ - I personally would simply write $\mathrm{Ult}_{U_n}(M)$ for the same structure as there is no possible cause for confusion.

Comment: But when I asked above: Do you mean "Let $M=\mathbb{Ult}_U(V)$" you answered  Yes, I've actually made that mistake twice in my comment but apparently only spotted it once. So you meant there $V$ rather then $M$. Why not now??

Comment: @user122424 Simply because we are talking about different structures. There are 3 models of set theory involved in this proof: 1. $V$, 2. $M = \mathrm{Ult}_{U_0}(V)$ and 3. $\mathrm{Ult}_{U_n}(M)$ - the latter of which is an ultrapower as constructed within $M$. The distinction between these models is crucial. In fact the only nontrivial part of the proof, in my opinion, is to see that we have enough agreement between $M$ and $\mathrm{Ult}_{U_n}(M)$ to conclude that $U_{n+1} \in \mathrm{Ult}_{U_n}(M)$.

Comment: OK. And what is the difference between $\mathbb{Ult}_{U_n}(M)$ and  $\mathbb{Ult}^M_{U_n}(V)$  and $\mathbb{Ult}^M_{U_n}(M)$  ?

Comment: @user122424 I'm not sure what $\mathrm{Ult}_{U_n}^M(V)$ is supposed to mean. [My guess is that all three structures are the same.] But $\mathrm{Ult}_{U_n}(M)$ and $\mathrm{Ult}_{U_n}^M(M)$ are the same structure (assuming $U_n \in M$) - they are the ultrapower associated to $U_n$ as computed in $M$. Or equivalently the ultrapower associated to $U_n$ whose equivalance classes only use functions $f \colon \kappa \to M$ with $f \in M$.

Comment: And may be, that $\mathbb{Ult}_{U_n}(M)$ and $\mathbb{Ult}^M_{U_n}(M)$ are not the same when $U_n\notin M$? Is there a visible example of this possibility?

Comment: @user122424 If $U_n \not \in M$, then $\mathrm{Ult}_{U_n}^M(M)$ doesn't make any sense. $M$ doesn't "see" the ultrafilter it's supposed to use to build an ultrapower. However, provided that $\mathcal{P}(\kappa) = \mathcal{P}^M(\kappa)$, it still makes sense to build $\mathrm{Ult}_{U_n}(M)$ in $V$ - we simply build the usual ultrapower but only use those functions that are elements of $M$.

Comment: Do you happen to know what Noah Schweber means by this:However, this is still fixable: all the "nonstandard" terms of the sequence that j adds come after all the "standard" terms.Are there more than 1 nonstandard term,namely the one at $\kappa$ ? How he sees this is true and how this helps us? He isn't replaying much to me.

Comment: I actually do not know what is a nonstandard term here. Every fixed $\theta$ below $\kappa$ is standard one.So are there any nonstandard terms at all?

Comment: Forget about "standard" vs "nonstandard" - that's an unfortunate choice of terminology here. What Noah is saying is that for any sequence $\vec{x} = (x_{\alpha} \mid \alpha < \kappa)$ (in $V$) we have that, by elementarity, $\pi(\vec{x}) \in M$ is a sequence of length $\pi(\kappa) > \kappa$. So there are elements in the sequence $\pi(\vec{x})$ that do not appear on the shorter sequence $\vec{x}$. But, again by elementarity, for every $\alpha < \kappa$ we have that the $\alpha$th element of $\pi(\vec{x})$ is equal to $\pi(x_{\alpha})$ which, in the case we care about, is just $x_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Hence $\pi(\vec{x})$ is a longer sequence than $\vec{x}$ but has $\vec{x}$ as an 'initial segment' provided that $\pi(x_{\alpha}) = x_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha < \kappa$.

Comment: How do we know that when we want to show that for all $a_{\eta}\in M$ for $\eta<\theta$ that $\langle a_{\eta}\rangle_{\eta<\theta}\in M$ there are actually $b_{\eta}$ with $j(b_{\eta})=a_{\eta}$ ?

Comment: @user122424 There aren't - in general. Take for example the sequence $(\alpha \mid \alpha < \kappa)$. It's easy to check that $j((\alpha \mid \alpha < \kappa)) = (\alpha \mid \alpha < j(\kappa))$, so $\kappa$ appears in this sequence. However $\kappa \not \in \mathrm{ran}(j)$ - as it is the critical point of $j$.

Comment: So why can he assume this, can you explain this to me in detail?

Comment: @user122424 I don't know what 'this' means and I suggest that whatever remains unclear, should be posted as a new question since we are getting way off-topic here.

Comment: OK. But I also do not understand your example that $\kappa\notin ran(j)$:$\kappa<j(\kappa)$ so $\kappa\in ran(j)$?

Comment: @user122424 That warrens its own question but it's true that $\kappa \not \in \mathrm{ran}(j) := \{ j(x) \mid x \in V \}$ and thus $\mathrm{ran}(j)$ is not transitive whereas $M$ is.

Comment: @user122424 I added a proof that $M$ is closed under $\kappa$-sequences.

Comment: How does it follow in your new answer that   $$\{ \xi < \kappa \mid g(\xi)(i) = f_{i}(\xi) \} = \kappa \setminus (i+1) $$ ?

Comment: @user122424 That's immediate from the definition of $g$. As soon as $\xi > i$ we have $g(\xi)(i) = f_{i}(\xi)$. If $\xi \le i$, then $g(\xi)(i)$ is not defined.

Comment: Final question: why $κ∖(i+1)∈U_0$?

Comment: @user122424 $U_0$ is an ultrafilter and uniform, i.e. every element of $U_0$ has cardinality $\kappa$. So $i+1 \not \in U_0$ and thus its complement $\kappa \setminus (i+1)$ must be in $U_0$. Proving that $U_0$ is uniform follows from normality and should be written somewhere in Jech's book. Otherwise, I think, this should be a separate question in case you can't prove it yourself.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot see now how did you use that $\kappa=[\mathbb{id}_\kappa]$?

Comment: @user122424 It's not essential to the proof but it is used to see that $\mathrm{dom}([g]) = [\mathrm{id}] = \kappa$. Otherwise the domain might be slightly larger - the proof would still work, though.