# The Mitchell order, unclear step in the proof of well-foundedness

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510951/the-mitchell-order)
in the first answer,
I do not understand the step that there **exist**
$\beta_\eta$ with $j(\beta_\eta)=\alpha_\eta$ for $\eta<\theta$
for some fixed $\theta<\kappa$ and for all $a_\eta\in M$.

I think that this is not true in general, but I don't know why we can be happy with this in that particular proof that $M^\kappa\subset M$
 . This last condition is what I would like to prove.

Answer (score 0):

It's a requirement that Noah poses on the sequence $(\alpha_\eta \mid \eta < \theta)$ - he doesn't claim that this is true for all sequences of length $< \kappa$.

Here is the relevant quote - the emphasize is mine.

> **Suppose** $a_\eta\in M$ with $a_\eta=j(b_\eta)$, for $\eta<\theta$ for some fixed $\theta<\kappa$. Then we have $j(\langle b_\eta\rangle_{\eta<\theta})=\langle a_\eta\rangle_{\eta<\theta}$: [..]

As I've pointed out in an earlier comment, this is in fact not always true. Consider for example the sequence $(\alpha_0) = (\kappa)$ of length $1$. Since $\kappa = \mathrm{crit}(j)$, there is no $\beta_0$ such that $j(\beta_0) = \alpha_0$. Hence we cannot apply Noah's argument to this sequence.

Comment: I also misinterpreted what you meant to ask in your earlier comment. I thought what troubled you is the fact that $\kappa$ has no preimage under $j$. My bad.

Comment: So I still do not understand why can we **suppose** this, while at the same time it is not always true.We want to show that for **each** $a_\eta$, the whole sequence lies in $M$, right?Not only the one hited with $j$.

Comment: @user122424 Oh, now I see your problem and you're right. Noah's answers, as written, doesn't show that $M$ is closed under $\kappa$-sequences. Sometimes being comfortable with a topic tends to make one blind to details. There is an easy fix and I'll add that fix to my answer of the previous question.

Comment: That's great, I'm extremely focused on detail in set theory.Thank you for your help.